# how to add coordinate array as rows in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a text file that looks like this

```
,A,B
0,"[[-81.03443909  29.22855949]
 [-81.09729767  29.27094078]
 [-80.9937973   29.19698906]
 [-81.03072357  29.27445984]
 [-81.00499725  29.22187805]]","[[-81.42427063  28.30874634]
 [-81.42427063  28.30874634]
 [-81.42427063  28.30874634]
 [-81.36068726  28.29172897]
 [-81.42297363  28.30497551]
 [-81.48571777  28.24975777]
 [-81.35914612  28.29036331]]"
```

This is what the `data` I'm using looks like, after it's put into a Pandas DataFrame

```
[[-78.70117188  33.80754852]
 [-78.9934082   33.61843491]
 [-80.81887817  28.60919952]
 ..., 
 [-76.62332916  35.54064941]
 [-79.04235077  33.81600952]
 [-79.03309631  33.55596161]]
```

And I would like it to look like this

```
                       lat      long 
cluster      point                              
0          a      0.445900 -1.286198 
           b     -0.574496 -0.407154 
           c      0.872979  0.068084 
           d      0.297255 -2.157051
```

Before I create the .txt file the data is in a `nd.array` and I'm using pandas to create the text file. So maybe there's a way I can skip the txt file and use pandas to split or format the array into a neat dataframe. I've been at this for a while and I can't figure out how.

This is how I generate my data. I'm keeping things clear by only copying 2 columns but in the future I would like to pass an unique point identifier

```
# Generate sample data
col_1 ="RL15_LONGITUDE"
col_2 ="RL15_LATITUDE"

data = pd.read_csv("input_data.csv")
coords = data.as_matrix(columns=[col_1, col_2])
data = data[[col_1,col_2]].dropna()
data = data.as_matrix().astype('float16',copy=False)
```

This is the output of `print clusters`

```
[array([[-81.03443909,  29.22855949],
       [-81.09729767,  29.27094078],
       [-81.42297363,  28.30497551],
       [-81.48571777,  28.24975777],
       [-81.35914612,  28.29036331]], dtype=float32), array([[-81.49134064,  27.58896065],
       [-81.5194931 ,  27.63422012],
       [-81.5096283 ,  27.55581093],
       [-82.05444336,  26.93555069]], dtype=float32), array([[-82.18956757,  26.52433586],
       [-82.18956757,  26.52433586],
       [-82.18956757,  26.52433586],
       [-82.19439697,  26.53297997]], dtype=float32)]
```

This is how I'm creating my dataframe and writing a `.txt` file

```
clusters = pd.DataFrame({'A':[clusters]})
clusters.to_csv('output.txt')
```

Comment: can you post a sample of `clusters` variable (i.e. output of `print(clusters)`), because it's going to be tricky to parse this file...

Comment: @MaxU, please see the edit. That is what the output (abbreviated) of `clusters` is.

Comment: Do all your clusters have the same # of points?

Comment: No, they don't. `clusters` is actually `clusters = [data[labels == i] for i in xrange(n_clusters_)]` which it's using the output of `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN()`. So each cluster will most likely be a different size

Comment: OK, could you also post an output of `print data`? I guess this one will be the most useful for producing a data frame...

Comment: I added the output of `data`. This is a dataframe, but it's reading from a `.csv` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

```
In [72]: (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['lat','lon']).assign(cluster=i)
   ....:             for i,c in enumerate(clusters)])
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....:    .rename(columns={'index':'point'})
   ....: )
Out[72]:
    point        lat        lon  cluster
0       0 -81.034439  29.228559        0
1       1 -81.097298  29.270941        0
2       2 -81.422974  28.304976        0
3       3 -81.485718  28.249758        0
4       4 -81.359146  28.290363        0
5       0 -81.491341  27.588961        1
6       1 -81.519493  27.634220        1
7       2 -81.509628  27.555811        1
8       3 -82.054443  26.935551        1
9       0 -82.189568  26.524336        2
10      1 -82.189568  26.524336        2
11      2 -82.189568  26.524336        2
12      3 -82.194397  26.532980        2
```

Or with a multi-index:

```
In [73]: (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['lat','lon']).assign(cluster=i)
   ....:             for i,c in enumerate(clusters)])
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....:    .rename(columns={'index':'point'})
   ....:    .set_index(['cluster','point'])
   ....: )
Out[73]:
                     lat        lon
cluster point
0       0     -81.034439  29.228559
        1     -81.097298  29.270941
        2     -81.422974  28.304976
        3     -81.485718  28.249758
        4     -81.359146  28.290363
1       0     -81.491341  27.588961
        1     -81.519493  27.634220
        2     -81.509628  27.555811
        3     -82.054443  26.935551
2       0     -82.189568  26.524336
        1     -82.189568  26.524336
        2     -82.189568  26.524336
        3     -82.194397  26.532980
```

Comment: WOW! Dude thank you so much! I spent the last day and half trying to figure this out!

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again

Comment: idk if this should be a different question but I was wondering if there's a quick way to link part of the source data (point name) to the point?

Comment: @rubito, but where those point names are coming from? I didn't see it in your source data set

Comment: Yeah I didn't add it because I didn't know it was gonna be an issue and to keep things clean. But basically each point has an identifier which is in the `.csv` that I read lat and long from. And I just noticed that I'm gonna need that since `float32` changes my coordinates enough to not be able to accurately look them up.

Comment: @rubito, i would recommend you to open a new question and post there a sample CSV (5-10) rows and desired output. Because this answer is based on __already processed__ `clusters` list